# Is strided numpy array shared across multiple processes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing, stride

Let`s assume that we created a numpy array with views on another array using stride tricks:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks
x = np.arange(20).reshape([4, 5])
arr = stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=(3, 2, 5),strides=(20, 20, 4))
```

We can confirm that this new array is indeed a view:

```
assert not arr.flags['OWNDATA']
# True
```

Question:

If I pass `arr` as an argument into `multiprocessing.Process()` will `arr` be copied into each process ? Will `x` be copied ? Please explain why.

Comment: I'd suggest experimenting with a small example.  I haven't used multiprocessing much, so can't say what happens to views.  While an `as_strided` view does not increase memory use, many operations using it do.  I recently helped a poster who found that `std` caused a memory error because it subtracts the mean from the view.

Comment: Yes, each argument is *pickled* then deserialized in the new process. Whether `x` is copied depends.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how could you deserialize without making a brand new copy?

Comment: @MarkRansom oh the arguments are always copied. `x` is a global variable. It depends on how/if `x` is used and how the process is created (e.g. fork vs spawn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sharing is via `pickle` serialization, then clearly the `view` (how ever generated) will produce a copy:

```
In [298]: x = np.arange(10)
In [299]: y = x.reshape(2,5)
In [300]: import pickle
In [301]: B = pickle.dumps(y)
In [302]: Y = pickle.loads(B)
In [303]: Y
Out[303]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [304]: y.__array_interface__['data']
Out[304]: (43176224, False)
In [305]: x.__array_interface__['data']
Out[305]: (43176224, False)
In [306]: Y.__array_interface__['data']
Out[306]: (59035584, False)
```

For what it's worth the `pickle` of a numpy array is actually performed by `np.save`.

Passing `x` and making the view in each process might be better.

Comment: "Passing `x` and making the view in each process might be better." - that's not going to avoid a copy.